# Firebase Notification onBackground don't work for Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

A background message could not be handled in Dart as no onBackgroundMessage handler has been registered.

add config on  AndroidManifest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an `onBackgroundMessage` handler in your `void main()` to handle the background messages you receive. Like this:

```
void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```